# Make a distribution list look at the mail attribute in ADUC

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Does anybody know if there is a way to make a distribution group (static or dynamic) look at the mail attribute in ADUC and send to that email address? For example, in my organization, we have people have mailboxes that end with "@subdomain.domain.com" and others who have @domain.com, both of which are written to the mail attribute in ADUC. Also, I don't manage domain.com at all and don't have permissions to.

The main part of my question is for a user who is not mail-enabled, can we make a distribution group that works for that person based on the mail attribute in ADUC. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear for mail enabled objects the Mail Attribute should reflect the PrimarySMTPAddress from the ProxyAddresses attribute. The ProxyAddresses property is the attribute that Exchange uses for delivery.  I would suggest you reword your question and included more details into what your trying to achieve to make it more precise. It sounds like you need some type of more complex address rewriting which you would need to use a Transport Agent for.

Comment: If the user does not have a PrimarySMTP address because it does not have a mailbox in my subdomain, we have to manually add their primary address at the domain.com to their mail attribute in ADUC so other things work, like digital senders. The main part of my question is for a user who is not mail-enabled, can we make a distribution group that works for that person based on the mail attribute in ADUC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found that what I'm looking for is the cmdlet "Enable-MailUser", which is different than creating a mail contact, as noted here https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/613/t/199455 and the reason this works for me better than making a mail contact is because mail users can be linked directly to the AD object as opposed to making a mail contact.